# NPM --proxy options works but setting proxy in config does not

Tags: npm

I am trying to set up a corporate proxy with npm. I would like to set it on my npm config so I don't have to specify it for each npm command.

The problem is I can't make the proxy work by setting it in the config. Here is my config file :

```
proxy=http://username:password@proxy_url.com:port
https-proxy=http://username:password@proxy_url.com:port
https_proxy=http://username:password@proxy_url.com:port
```

Running `npm install` causes a network error.

But **it does work** when I run `npm install` while setting the proxy :

```
npm --proxy http://"username:password"@proxy_url.com:80 install
```

Is there something I did wrong in the config ?

Answer (score 0):

Just had to clean the cache :

```
npm cache clean --force
```